# How to pass an intent using wifi P2P android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-developer-api

I am creating an app which sends an intent which triggers an activity in another phone. Both the phones are connected in the same network and also the number of peers will be variable. How can I implement this using wifi p2p. I want to broadcast this intent as well as listen to such broadcasts by other users of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WiFi P2P has only fixed set of broadcasts that can be received across device namely

- `WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`
- `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION`
- `WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION`
- `WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION`

You should define some sort application level protocol like after connecting if I receive `MessageA` I will use local broadcast manager to send `IntentA` to my other components. If I want other users to perform `ActionB` I will send them `MessageB` etc. Just a thought.

You could use [this](https://github.com/markrjr/Salut) wifi p2p wrapper to make your life more easier. You can keep your messages and its parameters as classes and send the class.

Comment: is there any other way for implementing this because not every phone supports wifi direct. I had thought about the way you said but the prob is i dont know where to start from. I have no idea how to send messages to a network connected using wifi router locally.

Comment: Well wifi direct is available from sdk 14 which should cover 90% of the phones on market. below that you could use bluetooth. example [link](https://github.com/simonguest/android-btxfr), you could add a feature even for NFC file sharing  [link](http://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/index.html). You definitely have to follow Adapter or Strategy design pattern to use appropriate file sharing tactics based on different device.

Comment: Can you tell me where i can learn how to use wifi connection for sending messagesin local network? I am stuck right now i dont know where to go.